# Is there a DisplayName attribute in CakePHP as there is in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: cakephp

I'm aware of the "conventions over configurations" philosophy beyond CakePHP. The "bake all" command generates automatically Models, Controllers and Views by using english language conventions. The problem is that the website I'm making needs to be in spanish. I can code the back-end (database and MVC stuff) in english but the automatic view it's rendered in english too and I need it in spanish.

In MVC I can just add a DisplayName attribute to the model (anyway, I never had problems with writing the names in spanish) so the view will show it, instead of the name of the field in the database/model.
So, Does CakePHP have a easy way to do the same? Do I have to modify each automatic view or create my own?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by following the steps on this link: http://colorblindprogramming.com/multiple-languages-in-a-cakephp-2-application-in-5-steps

Comment: @Aparna The linked article has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I gave you that link for multiple language option.

Comment: @Aparna Read the question again, it's not about multi-language options/switching languages. Also, I'm not the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such property, no, however baked view templates are by default using translation functions for all output, so you could simply create proper spanish translations and you should be good.

See

- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization (CakePHP 3)](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Utilities > Internationalization & Localization (CakePHP 2)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)**

Comment: Also the generated labels for inputs: $this->Form->input('field_name');? Because it doesn't have the translation function syntax __('String displayed').

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz Yes, that happens inside of the form helper (unless you pass the `label` option).

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help